# Python: how to combine a list of lists for a dictionary key

Tags: python, list, key, frame

My dictionary, 'ex' looks like this:

```
ex = {'G1': ['D1','D9', ['A1', 'H1', 'I1']], 'D5': ['D4', ['A5', 'G5', 'H5', 'I5']]}
```

I wish to simply have a list of values each key and not a list that also has a list within it. How should I go about doing this? So that my list looks like:

```
ex = {'G1': ['D1','D9','A1', 'H1', 'I1'], 'D5': ['D4','A5', 'G5', 'H5', 'I5']}
```

The way I ended up with my dict like so was by appending a list to my 'ex' dict like this:

```
ex[key].append([list])
```

'ex' had previously had a list of values for each key, and upon appending a new list resulted in this nesting which I would like to fix.

Comment: How did this list come about? Have you looked up how to flatten lists? You should share some code.

Comment: Can the lists be nested **arbitrary deep**? Or is the maximum depth 2?

Comment: @Willem max depth is 2

Comment: Look at itertools.chain_from_iterable

Comment: that ends up breaking up my string values to 'B', '1', etc.

Comment: To avoid the nesting you should use `.extend` instead of `.append`.

Comment: @PM2Ring exactly, my suspicion is that you can fix this at the source, rather than flatten later.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks for @PM2RING's reminding,you can just update `ex`:

```
ex = {'G1': ['D1','D9', ['A1', 'H1', 'I1']], 'D5': ['D4', ['A5', 'G5', 'H5', 'I5']]}

for k,v in ex.items():
    tmp=[]
    for i in v:
        if isinstance(i,list):
            tmp.extend(i)
        else:
            tmp.append(i)
    ex[k]=tmp

print ex
```

Output:

```
{'D5': ['D4', 'A5', 'G5', 'H5', 'I5'], 'G1': ['D1', 'D9', 'A1', 'H1', 'I1']}
```

Comment: Thank you, this was the answer that I was looking for!

Comment: @Cora You really should fix the code that updates `ex` to use `.extend`, rather than using code afterwards to fix the unwanted nesting.

Comment: BTW, you can safely modify `ex`, there's no need to build a new dict. In fact, you could even modify the `v` lists in-place using `v[:]=` assignment if you want to, although it's slightly faster to just use new lists.

Comment: @PM2Ring Thanks for your reminding,I update my answer.